# Can't use the event scheduler in PHP My Admin, how to make a PHP file for cron?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, cron, buddypress

I have the following code to delete all Buddypress activity older than 24 hours.

```
DELETE FROM wp_bp_activity WHERE date_recorded < (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

But my hosting provider is not allowing to use the event scheduler, so i can not automatic run it. Someone who knows how I can run it with a PHP script and then schedule it with a cron?

Answer (score 0):

you can cron job with a mysql script as well see [mysql command line](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/command-line-options.html) for more options

```
mysql -u username -p password -e "DELETE FROM wp_bp_activity WHERE date_recorded < (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using WordPress, you might be able to make use of WP-Cron, placeing there somewhere in you functions.php should do the work:

```
add_action('wp', 'wp4312121_setup_daily_cron');
function wp4312121_setup_daily_cron() {

  if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'wp4312121_daily_cron_hook' )) {
      $firstRun = time();
       wp_schedule_event($firstRun, 'daily', 'wp4312121_daily_cron_hook');
  }

}
add_action('wp4312121_daily_cron_hook', 'wp4312121_daily_cron');
function wp4312121_daily_cron() {

  global $wpdb;

  $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'bp_activity';
  $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `$table` WHERE date_recorded < (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)" );


}
```

You can read more about [WordPress Cron here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/).